# Store user selected country in cookies with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am using cookies to store user selected country. There is only two options - Latvia or Estonia.

Problem is that sometimes when I want to change country it works. But sometimes it won't I can click as much as I want but country won't change. And other times after F5 or Refresh previusly selected country changes to other one.

My code so far.

**Application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_location

def set_location
     if cookies[:estonia] == '1' 
            @location = Country.find(2)            
     elsif cookies[:latvia] == '1'
            @location = Country.find(1)
     else       
         if  request.location.country == 'Latvia'
            @location = Country.find(1)            
         elsif request.location.country == 'Estonia'         
                     @location = Country.find(2) 
         else
                     @location = Country.find(1)
         end
     end
end
```

in Layout

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function latvia(){
                   days=1; // number of days to keep the cookie
                   myDate = new Date();
                   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                   document.cookie = 'latvia=1; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
                   document.cookie = "estonia=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
                }

   function estonia(){
                   days=1; // number of days to keep the cookie
                   myDate = new Date();
                   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                   document.cookie = 'estonia=1; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
                   document.cookie = "latvia=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
                }

</script>
```

And Location selection:

```
<% if @location.id == 1%>
   <li> <%= link_to "Igaunija ", root_path,  :onclick => 'estonia()'%></li>  

  <%else%>
   <li> <%= link_to "Latvija ", root_path,  :onclick => 'latvia()'%></li> 

  <%end%>
```

This change aviable location option based on which is already selected.

In Mozilla firebug I can't see any errors related to cookies.
When I clean website data such cookies and history then for some time it works again just fine.

So what could couse these problems ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to know your requirements, but I would omit that javascript part and set those cookies using just Rails. I guess you'd need to supply default country and I'm not sure why you need to set it at `root_path`.
I wouldn't use those cryptic ID keys to determine location, instead I'd use symbols `country: :latvia`, `country: :estonia`.
I guess it all depends on your use-case.

```
# View
<% if @location.id == 1%>
  <li> <%= link_to "Igaunija ", root_path(country_id: 1) %></li>  
<%else%>
  <li> <%= link_to "Latvija ", root_path(country_id: 2) %></li> 
<%end%>


# Controller
before_filter :set_location

def set_location
  @location = Country.find(current_location_id)
  cookies[:country_id] = @location.id
end

def  current_location_id
  params[:country_id] || cookies[:country_id] || 1
end
```

The hardcoded '1' is not a good practice. I'd use country symbols: :en, :lv, :est
Then instead of '1' you could create a method, that returns default location.

```
Country.default_location #=> :lv
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code gives me `Couldn't find Country without an ID` I guess its because I havent choosen location yet. But how can I  set default location ?